# Error with ieeeaccess.cls "Missing number, treated as zero. \xdef"

Tags: pdftex

I'm using the ieeeaccess.cls for IEEE Access journal but I get the following error,

```
Missing number, treated as zero. \xdef
```

My code is as follows,

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, color, enumerate, amsthm, graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz, subcaption, cite}
\usepackage{color, xcolor, soul, bm, textcomp}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
  urlcolor     = blue, %Colour for external hyperlinks
  linkcolor    = blue, %Colour of internal links
  citecolor    = green %Colour of citations
}

\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\usepackage{epsfig} 
\usepackage{psfrag}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
        T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}


\def\endtheorem{\hspace*{\fill}~$\square$\par\endtrivlist\unskip}
\def\endlemma{\hspace*{\fill}~$\square$\par\endtrivlist\unskip}
\def\endproposition{\hspace*{\fill}~$\square$\par\endtrivlist\unskip}
\def\endexample{\hspace*{\fill}~$\square$\par\endtrivlist\unskip}
\def\endremark{\hspace*{\fill}~$\square$\par\endtrivlist\unskip}
\def\enddefinition{\hspace*{\fill}~$\square$\par\endtrivlist\unskip}

\begin{document}
\history{Date of publication xxxx 00, 0000, date of current version xxxx 00, 0000.}
\doi{10.1109/ACCESS.2017.DOI}

\title{My title}

\author{\uppercase{Mohammad}\authorrefmark{1}}
\address[1]{Department of Electrical and Computer Engineering (e-mail: myemail@mydomain.edu)}

\markboth
{Author \headeretal: Preparation of Papers for IEEE TRANSACTIONS and JOURNALS}
{Author \headeretal: Preparation of Papers for IEEE TRANSACTIONS and JOURNALS}

\corresp{Corresponding author: Mohammad}

\newcommand{\ty}{\color{yellow}}
\newcommand{\tb}{\color{blue}}
\newcommand{\tr}{\color{red}}
\newcommand{\tg}{\color{green}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{abstract}
My abstract ...
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
    My keywords ...
\end{keywords}

\titlepgskip=-15pt

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}
\PARstart{T}{his} is my document.

%\appendices
%\input{Appendix}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv, refs}

\EOD

\end{document}
```

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: File `ieeeaccess.cls' not found.`  can you link to the class?

Comment: probably unrelated but no document written after 1993 should be using `\usepackage{epsfig} ` the package was written then to emulate the old latex2.09 package of that name, to help port documents that were old in 1993 move to the new LaTeX2e standard from LaTeX2.09.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-journal-article/authoring-tools-and-templates/ieee-article-templates/templates-for-ieee-access/

Comment: The duplicate question points to `forest`, but the workaround is the same with `tcolorbox` instead. However you should remove the previous loading of `tikz`, for simplicity. As explained in my answer, the issue is that the class redefines `\year`, which is a ***very bad*** thing to do.

Comment: @egreg Thanks! I fixed that but now I'm getting this error: "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{thebibliography}" and all of my references appear as [?].

Comment: @egreg Also the \ref command doesn't work properly. For example, "Proof of Theorem~\ref{thm: my theorem}" produces "Proof of Theorem ??".

Comment: Not in my test: did you run LaTeX twice? Please, open a new question for that with example of what goes wrong. By the way, all your redefinitions of `\endtheorem` and similar are flawed.

Comment: @egreg I ran it twice and solved. Why the redefinitions are flawed?

Comment: Because they don't ensure the square will be at the end of a line. Besides, there's no reason to end *statements* of theorems with a square.

Comment: @egreg But the command \hspace*{\fill} ensures the square will be at the end of a line. Doesn't it?

Comment: @egreg I just noticed that Appendices doesn't print the correct word APPENDIX. It just puts a dot there. Besides, \ref doesn't work when it's used in section headers. For example, the command "\section{Proof of Lemma~\ref{lem:mylemma}}\label{app:proofdirtreehinf}" produces Proof of Lemma ??; however, it works in the paper text.

Comment: I made a new question regarding my last comment https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517162/ref-doesnt-work-in-the-section-header-in-ieeeaccess-cls

Comment: @egreg I removed tcolorbox and tikz packages and everything works now. But how can I put a box in my paper using tcolorbox? I mean: \begin{tcolorbox} my box \end{tcolorbox}

Comment: @egreg Could you please help me with this? The command \hspace*{\fill} ensures the square will be at the end of a line. Doesn't it?

Comment: @Mohammad No, it doesn't: if `\hfill` is used as a line break point it disappears.

Comment: @egreg I see, so may I replace \fill with \hfill to remedy it? How can I modify my command to ensure that?