# \ref doesn't work in the section header in ieeeaccess.cls

Tags: pdftex

I'm using the `ieeeaccess.cls` for IEEE Access journal. I noticed that Appendices doesn't print the correct word APPENDIX. It just puts a dot there. Besides, `\ref` doesn't work when it's used in section headers. For example, the command:

```
\section{Proof of Lemma~\ref{lem:mylemma}}\label{app:proofdirtreehinf}
```

produces:

> Proof of Lemma

However, it works in the paper text.

One more problem is that I have a formula in one of the section headers which is `$f > 1$` but the `ieeeaccess.cls` makes it capital as F > 1. How can I make it lowercase?

My code is as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, color, enumerate, amsthm, graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption, cite}
\usepackage{color, xcolor, soul, bm, textcomp}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
  urlcolor     = blue, %Colour for external hyperlinks
  linkcolor    = blue, %Colour of internal links
  citecolor    = green %Colour of citations
}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
        T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\begin{document}
\history{Date of publication xxxx 00, 0000, date of current version xxxx 00, 0000.}
\doi{10.1109/ACCESS.2017.DOI}

\title{My title}

\author{\uppercase{Mohammad}\authorrefmark{1}}
\address[1]{Department of Electrical and Computer Engineering (e-mail: myemail@mydomain.edu)}

\markboth
{Author \headeretal: Preparation of Papers for IEEE TRANSACTIONS and JOURNALS}
{Author \headeretal: Preparation of Papers for IEEE TRANSACTIONS and JOURNALS}

\corresp{Corresponding author: Mohammad}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{abstract}
My abstract ...
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
    My keywords ...
\end{keywords}

\titlepgskip=-15pt

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}
\PARstart{T}{his} is my document.
\begin{lemma}\label{lem:mylemma}
This is my lemma
\end{lemma}
\section{$f>1$ case: Proof of Lemma~\ref{lem:mylemma}}

\appendices
\input{Appendix}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{refs}

\EOD

\end{document}
```

Comment: Link to `ieeeaccess.cls`: [Templates for IEEE Access](https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-journal-article/authoring-tools-and-templates/ieee-article-templates/templates-for-ieee-access/)

Comment: @Werner Thanks. I should have included the link in my question!

Comment: We don't have `Appendix.tex`, so we can't really address your concerns around the appendix. Either provide that file as part of your question, or replace it with the code contained within `Appendix.tex` as part of the main code.

Comment: @Werner The Appendix.tex

\section{Proof of Lemma~\ref{lem:mylemma}} This is my proof ...

Comment: Just a remark: the definition of `\BibTeX` is completely useless, remove it.

Comment: For lowercasing in the math mode, you can use `\lowercase{}` command. Use it as `\section{\lowercase{$f>1$} case: Proof of Lemma~\ref{lem:mylemma}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I cannot reproduce the issue with the disappearing "Appendix". So I cannot help you there.
2. The Compilation log tells you exactly what is wrong with the missing references, which also hints at what is wrong with the `$f > 1$`. The log shows:

   ```
   ....
   LaTeX Warning: Reference `LEM:MYLEMMA' on page 1 undefined on input line 56.
   ....
   ```

   and you ask yourself, why does it say 'LEM:MYLEMMA' as opposed to 'lem:mylemma'? Then you go into the class file and find that they redefined the section command to read

   ```
   \def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{1pt}{-1pc plus -1pt minus -1pt}%
         {0.001pt}{\raggedright\color{accessblue}\sectionAfont\uppercase}}%
   ```

   notice how the command ends with `\uppercase`. That's your culprit right there. If I remove the `\uppercase` command from the class definition, then all's well.
3. The issue with the `\uppercase` command is well-known: see [this TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-casechange). And you can also use the same work-around. For example, define a new command

   ```
    \newcommand*\pfoflma{PROOF OF LEMMA~\ref{lem:mylemma}}
   ```

   and instead of writing `\section{Proof of Lemma ~\ref{lem:mylemma}}`, you can write

   ```
    \section{\protect\pfoflma}
   ```

   You can do something similar with the math expression by hiding it behind a macro and protecting it from expansion.
4. Probably you should bring this to the attention of the journal, and maybe you should check with them to see if they have any house rules against using mathematics expressions in the section titles (otherwise surely someone would've run into this already).